# Type inference for class member

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Using `TypeVar` and `Generic`, I can create classes with methods where types can be [inferred](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#defining-generic-classes) , e.g.:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Box(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, content: T) -> None:
        self.content = content

Box(1)  # OK, inferred type is Box[int]
```

Is it possible to infer types of a class member? Let's say I have different types of athletes' stats:

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Type


class Stats(ABC):
    pass


class BaseballStats(Stats):
    @property
    def batting_average(self) -> float:
        return 0.314


class FootballStats(Stats):
    @property
    def yards(self) -> int:
        return 314
```

And now I want to define an abstract class for an athlete:

```
S = TypeVar('S', bound=Stats)


class Athlete(ABC, Generic[S]):
    _stats_type: Type[S]

    @property
    def stats(self) -> S:
        return self._stats_type()
```

If I try to make a `BaseballPlayer` and have it infer the type by assigning to `_stats_type`, it won't:

```
class BaseballPlayer(Athlete):
    _stats_type = BaseballStats


bo = BaseballPlayer()
# reveal_type(bo.stats) --> gives `Any`; type was not inferred
print(bo.stats.batting_average)  # works.
```

If I specify the type of `Athlete` but don't assign `_stats_type`, it won't run.

```
class FootballPlayer(Athlete[FootballStats]):
    pass


bo = FootballPlayer()
# reveal_type(bo.stats) --> gives `FootballStats` because I explcitly called it out
print(bo.stats.yards)  # AttributeError: 'FootballPlayer' object has no attribute '_stats_type'
```

Is there an alternative that doesn't require that I put the type of statistics in two places? I.e., can I avoid doing this?

```
class FootballPlayer(Athlete[FootballStats]):
    _stats_type = FootballStats
```

Comment: fairly certain the answer's no. `Athlete` is, as far as type checking is concerned, `Athlete[Any]`. And Python won't generate your runtime `_stats_type` from your type type parameterization `Athlete[FootballStats]` (unless you mess with `__class_getitem__` which I don't recommend)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you pretty much have to specify the type of `Athlete` when defining the subclasses, otherwise mypy will complain with the following:

```
error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Athlete"  [type-arg]
```

Now, contrary to your `Box` example, your issue is that you want to have the type **at runtime** (so that you can instantiate it in `stats`).

My experience (shared also by others, see e.g. [beartype](https://github.com/beartype/beartype)) is that using types hints at runtime is a bit clunky to say the least.

With that being said, you can probably do something like below, which gets the type at runtime from the `Athlete` your class is inheriting from. It is based on `__orig_bases__` from [PEP 560](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/#mro-entries).

```py
from typing import cast, get_args, get_origin


class Athlete(ABC, Generic[S]):
    @property
    def _stats_type(self) -> Type[S]:
        for orig_bases in self.__orig_bases__:
            if get_origin(orig_bases) == Athlete:
                return cast(Type[S], get_args(orig_bases)[0])
        raise RuntimeError  # should not happen

    @property
    def stats(self) -> S:
        return self._stats_type()


class FootballPlayer(Athlete[FootballStats]):
    pass

bo = FootballPlayer()
#reveal_type(bo.stats) --> gives `FootballStats`
print(bo.stats.yards)
```

Please note however the following warning about `__orig_bases__` from the PEP:

> NOTE: These two method names are reserved for use by the typing module and the generic types machinery, and any other use is discouraged.